# How do the clients register at openfire server?

Tags: java, xmpp, openfire

I have installed *openfire*. How can the clients register themselves on the server ? Do I have to write separate code for that ? I mean, do I have to write some kind of action handler for that ?

Comment: How do you want the clients to register themselves?  OpenFire can use a local user database with registration of users, or an LDAP database where the users are populated in some other way.

Comment: @ShaneMadden with a local user database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a plugin to handle user registration.  See [here](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/registration/readme.html).

Comment: Can I do it manually ? Like using a web form for user registration

Comment: On that page "Web Page Registration - Allows users to create accounts via a web page."

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I didn't get you

Comment: @SuhailGupta Answer is yes - the plugin provides a registration web page.

Comment: @ShaneMadden Can I code that myself?

Comment: @SuhailGupta So you're saying you're looking to write a custom web interface instead of using the one provided by the plugin?  That should be doable, I think..

Comment: @ShaneMadden yeah. Can I do this with `smack api` ?

Comment: @ShaneMadden and where is the download link for the registration plugin ?

Comment: @SuhailGupta Seems that you can indeed register users via smack, see this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892419 - the registration plugin and a number of others can be downloaded from here: http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins.jsp